# Missing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` of version `2.2.8` on `Ubuntu 20.04` after clean installation

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-20.04

Having issues with Ubuntu 20.04. I followed [official instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004-) and installed both SDK & runtime. If can be confirmed from the terminal:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.403 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

and runtime:

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

...yet the project I am trying to `dotnet run` requires the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8` as can be seen from the log:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.8' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.9 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=2.2.8&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.20.04-x64
```

What's the correct way to install missing SDKs and runtimes?

Comment: _You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK._

Comment: I just don’t see the right command to do that easily.

Answer (score 1):

So it comes out that `Ubuntu 20.04` is not supported for above-mentioned runtime and  one have to install them manually.
In my particular case it was enough [to download binaries](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) and run them as usual.